# OpenHTMLtoPDF Custom Page Size

Tags: c#, openhtmltopdf

I am trying to set a custom page size with `OpenHTMLtoPDF`. I am trying to convert an HTML source to a 58mm x 110mm thermal paper print job, however, I got stuck on this.

I have tried setting the page size directly like so:

```
var pdf = Pdf.From(html).OfSize(58,110);//Invalid arguments
```

and

```
var pdf = Pdf.From(html).OfSize(new PaperSize(58,110));//Invalid arguments
```

Comment: I posted this as a Q&A style question as I got stuck on this for an hour, and was unable to find anything on how to do this. After playing around for an hour I figured it out and thought it was worth sharing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are defining the size incorrectly.

What you need to do is create a new paper size like so:

```
OpenHtmlToPdf.PaperSize size = new OpenHtmlToPdf.PaperSize(Length.Millimeters(58), Length.Millimeters(110));
```

Then to set your PDF document to have the right paper size you would call this like so

```
var pdf = Pdf.From(html).OfSize(size);
```

---

**Side Note**

If you are using a different unit of measurement you can define what unit of measurement you are using like so:

```
Length.Inches(MeasurementInInches);
Length.Centimeters(MeasurementInCentimeters);
```

Comment: Is there any possibility for fixed width and dynamic height?(set the height to the final html element height)  for like thermal printer paper.

Comment: @qakmak not that I know of. One solution would be to roughly calculate the size based off the number of lines to be printed.

Comment: I think that's not a good solution, because the words in html, it might be auto-break to new line, in that cause I wouldn't know the number of lines....

Comment: There’s one more solution I can think of. Do a test with a set paper size (100mm) then see how many pages (lets say 4 pages in the test) it is and then rerun it with the set size and the number of pages so then you would have 400mm page height.

Comment: Sounds like a really good idea, but I think I need to find an external library for check PDF page size too, OpenHTMLtoPDF can't check it...

Comment: You should just be able to calculate it cause you are setting the page size yourself. But if you still need a library for pdf info you should checkout pdflib it worked well for me in a past project

Comment: Um..., I can set the height of page, but I still need to check the final generated pdf file page count. at the end I use PdfReader of pdfium, because it's free.  Thanks for give me good advice.

Comment: What version of OpenHtmlToPdf are you using? 
I tried the above and my pdf is 280mm x 360mm - no idea why